# In a game show database scenario, how do I fetch the average total episode score per season in a single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Pardon the title gore. I'm having trouble finding a good way to express my question, which is endemic to the problem.

### The Tables

**season**

```
  id   name  
 ---- ------ 
   1   Season 1
   2   Season 2
   3   Season 3
```

**episode**

```
  id   season_id   number                   title                  
 ---- ----------- -------- --------------------------------------- 
   1           1        1   Pilot                                  
   2           1        2   1x02 - We Got Picked Up                
   3           1        3   1x03 - This is the Third Episode       
   4           2        1   2x01 - We didn't get cancelled.        
   5           2        2   2x02 - We're running out of ideas!     
   6           3        1   3x01 - We're still here.               
   7           3        2   3x02 - Okay, this game show is dying.  
   8           3        3   3x03 - Untitled
```

**score**

```
  id   episode_id   score   contestant_id (table not given)  
 ---- ------------ ------- --------------------------------- 
   1            1      35                                 1  
   2            1     -12                                 2  
   3            1       8                                 3  
   4            1       5                                 4  
   5            2      13                                 1  
   6            2      -2                                 5  
   7            2       3                                 3  
   8            2     -14                                 6  
   9            3   -14.5                                 1  
  10            3      -3                                 2  
  11            3     1.5                                 7  
  12            3     9.5                                 5  
  13            4    22.8                                 1  
  14            4      -3                                 8  
  15            5       2                                 1  
  16            5    13.5                                 9  
  17            5       7                                 3  
  18            6      13                                 1  
  19            6     -84                                10  
  20            6      12                                11  
  21            7       3                                 1  
  22            7      10                                 2  
  23            8      29                                 1  
  24            8       1                                 5
```

As you can see, you have multiple episodes per season, and multiple scores per episode (one score per contestant). Contestants can reappear in later episodes (irrelevant), scores are floating point values, and there can be an arbitrary number of scores per episode.

### So what am I looking for?

I'd like to get the average total episode score per season, where the total episode score is the sum of all the scores in an episode. Mathematically, this comes out to be the sum of all scores in a season divided by the number of episodes. Easy enough to comprehend, but I have had trouble doing it in a single query and getting the correct result. I'd like an output like the following:

```
    name     average_total_episode_score  
 ---------- ----------------------------- 
  Season 1                          9.83  
  Season 2                         21.15  
  Season 3                         -5.33
```

The top-level query needs to be on the **`season`** table as it will be combined with other, similar queries on the same table. It's easy enough to do this with an aggregate in a subquery, but an aggregation executes the subquery, failing my single-query requirement. Can this be done in a single query?

Comment: In score table you have episode_id. How do you know which episode will correspond to a particular season? I dont find any season id in score table

Comment: `score`s are keyed to a single `episode` which is keyed to a single `season`.

Comment: My question is, you have many 1s in episode_id column of score. How do you know which season's first episode is that?

Comment: `score.episode_id` is referring to `episode.id` which is unique, not `episode.number` which is not unique. Confusing with so many numbers, I know. This is a bare representation of an actual database, so I wanted to include just enough for the question, but not the whole database. The _real_ `episode` table also includes columns such as `airdate`, `date_recorded`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just figured it out. As usual, I had to write and post a whole book before the simple solution descended upon me.

The problem in my query (which I didn't give in the question) was the lack of a `DISTINCT` count. Here is a working query:

```
SELECT
  "season"."id",
  "season"."name",
  (SUM("score"."score") / COUNT(DISTINCT "episode"."id")) AS "average_total_episode_score"
FROM "season"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "episode"
  ON ("season"."id" = "episode"."season_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "score"
  ON ("episode"."id" = "score"."episode_id")
GROUP BY "season"."id"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this should work

```
Select s.id, avg(score)
  FROM Season S,
       Episode e,
       Score sc
 WHERE s.id = e.season_id
   AND e.id = sc.episode_id
Group by s.id
```

Answer (score -1):

select Se.id AS Season_Id, sum(score) As season_score, avg(score)  from score S join episode E ON S.episode_id = E.id 
join Season se ON se.id = e.season_id group by se.id